# Making a real table with Laravel, using my data from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

it's me again with some Laravel questions, I need help with making a table in Laravel, like this: [image: Table 1]

What I have until now, is this: 
[image: Table 2]

This is my controller:

```
$workplaces = DB::table('activities')
 ->orderBy('workplace')
 ->select('workplace', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
 ->groupby('workplace')
 ->get();
```

This is my blade view:

```
<tr>
    <td>Workplaces</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</tr>
@foreach($workplaces as $workplace)
<tr>
    <td>{{$workplace->name}}
    <td>{{$workplace->total}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

An user from here helped me to make it count all activities, it helped a lot, but now I can't make it count the actives activities and inactives.

I've just tried to make two selects in one db::raw but it doesn't work, i've tried to  have two variables like $workspaces and $workspaces_active_activities, but doesn't work too, I can't make two foreachs inside another one.

Sorry for my bad english, hope you guys understand it. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Do you have active or inactive column in database ?

Comment: Yes, i have a "STATUS" column, sorry, forgot to mention, and inside it goes active or inactive

Comment: How you can specify active or inactive with just a single status column ?

Comment: it's not a single status, activities can be active, inactive, concluded or not conclued in status column in my database

Comment: So how are you storing the data in status column ? I mean in `1` or `0` form or in string form like `active`, `inactive` etc....

Comment: Sorry Akhtar, I'm storing in a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213636/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-lucas-vasconcelos).

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using eloquent for this? it feels like it would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your controller do this. But make sure to change `strict => false` in `config/database.php/connections/mysql` to make it work.

```
$workplaces = DB::table('activities')->select( array(
              DB::raw( 'workspace_name, activity_name' ),
              DB::raw( 'COUNT(*) as `total`' ),
              DB::raw(
              "SUM(CASE
                WHEN status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Active'"
              ),
              DB::raw(
              "SUM(CASE
                WHEN status = 'inActive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'inActive'"
              )
              ) )
              ->groupBy('workspace_name')
              ->get();
```

Comment: Sorry Akhtar, what I want to do is: I have so many lines in the query, I want to filter the activities, by workplace and status, my activities can have status active, inactive stored in a string

Comment: So, the 1 and 0 is the total numbers of activities that are show in the query, not true or false, can you understand what i'm saying or is confusing? Sorry again Akhtar, I think i don't express myself correctly

Comment: Akhtar, thank you so much brother, for you patience and attention, you're awesome